# Test bench when design is pipelined

Tags: system-verilog, rtl, testbench, verification

I have a design with chained modules. Each of them is a pipelined design, so the output in each of them take more than 1 clock cycle. To perform the test bench, I have created so many registered signals as stages in the pipelined designs to delay my gold test and compare it with the real output. An example:

```
// If module 1 has 4 stages:
reg [31:0] G1, G2, G3, G4;
always @(posedge CLK) begin
    G2 <= G1;
    G3 <= G2;
    // This is the the gold test bench synchronyzed 
    // with the output from the pipelined module
    G4 <= G3; 
end
```

In this way, I can compare the output of my module with the gold test. Other way is using time delays:

```
always
    #50 GOLD = output_from_module;
```

What is the best way to check an output that is delayed more than one clock cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to delay the driving of a signal `a` with `data` by `n` clock signals, you can use

`a <= repeat(n) @(posedge clk) data;`

This will drive `a` with `data` on the
\$n^{th}\$ rising edge of the clock. For more details refer to the SystemVerilog LRM.

Then you can compare it with the golden reference model's value using an assertion.